# Using the word "Phalanx" as a title

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Is there a verb for *phalanx*? I searched online dictionaries, but I didn't find it.

Can I use *Phalanx* as a title of my story?

I am just wondering whether I should use a verb, or a noun for titles.

Comment: What would you suppose the definition of the verb form of *phalanx* to be?  2. You can name your story anything you want- you're the author.  There are many famous stories that have nouns and noun phrases as titles. And you have your choice of naming it simply *Phalanx* or  *The Phalanx*

Comment: You [won't be the first either](http://www.amazon.com/Phalanx-Super-Nintendo/dp/B00002SV32).

Comment: @Jim: Thank you. Could you tell me the verb form of Phalanx.

Comment: It doesn't have a verb form. You can form a phalanx?

Comment: Merriam-Webster's 3rd Unabridged Dictonary of English -- Main Entry:2phalanx
Function:transitive verb 
Inflected Form:-ed/-ing/-es 

 : to form into a phalanx (back of him the graduating class was phalanxed— J.T.Farrell) (whose homes are in the phalanxed apartment buildings and hotels nearby— American Guide Series: New York City)

Comment: This question seems like those questions asking for the word to use as name of a variable used in some programming language. You can use any title you want, even a not grammatical word. Just see the titles used on newspapers, and magazines: There are titles that use phrases nobody would normally use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 dictionary.reference.com records *phalanx* as both *noun* and *verb*:

> **[phalanxed](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/phalanxed)**
>   *verb (used without object)*
>   **8** *Printing*. to arrange the distribution of work in a shop as evenly as possible.

Wordnik lists several examples of verb use (*[**phalanxed**](http://www.wordnik.com/words/phalanxed)*), including:

> “The whole while the procession made its way through the streets, they were carefully monitored and phalanxed the whole way by riot police.” *CNN Transcript - Special Event: Democratic National Convention: Joseph Lieberman to Give Keynote Address - August 16, 2000*
>
> “This is the secret of Shakespeare's strength in 'Hamlet,' as it is the purpose of Burke's in such speeches as that at the trial of Hastings, to compel immediate comprehension by crowding his meaning on the hearer in phalanxed sentences, moving to the attack, rank on rank, so that the first are at once supported and compelled by those which succeed them.” *The World's Best Orations, Vol. 1 (of 10)*
>
> “If the public suffered from these phalanxed industries while they ran smoothly, it endured peculiar evils from the periodical conflicts between the capital and the labor engaged in them.” *History of the United States, Volume 6 (of 6)*

[Bulletin of the Department of Labor, Volume 9, Issues 54-55](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=J5YCAAAAIAAJ&q=phalanxed&dq=phalanxed) records usage of both noun and verb forms:
"On six-day papers (by which is meant offices issuing one or more editions six days of each week), **phalanxing** shall not be permissible. On seven-day papers (by which is meant offices issuing one or more editions seven days of each week), **phalanxing** is permissible, but no employee of a seven-day paper shall be **phalanxed** more than one day of each current seven-day week. In offices where **phalanxes** occur, each employee must be phalanxed in order... " [emphasis mine]

"It is old as the Normans, I should think, that square tower, so massy and low, firm as the rock, so **phalanxed** and solid in its imperturbable immovability." ([Charles Dickens - 1860](http://books.google.com/books?id=OW4HAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA208&dq=phalanxed&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7TPhUN-wE8KrrAehzYCYDw&ved=0CFcQ6AEwCA))  [emphasis mine]

2 Why would one concern with the POS of a title? Shouldn't any do? OP's issue with using a verb or noun form is not clear.

Comment: I have to admire the polysemy in "the POS of a title".